# What does // ''; mean in Perl when concatenated at the end of the string?

Tags: perl

I looked around on google and couldn't find anything to explain what // '' means when it is at the end of the Perl expression e.g.

```
my $username = $cgi->param('username') // '';
```

The only thing I could think of is it sets username to empty string in the form, similar to what value='' does inside of  tags in HTML but I'm not sure.

Comment: `my $username = defined($cgi->param('username')) ? $cgi->param('username') : '';` if you're familiar with ternary operator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`//` is the [defined-or operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Defined-Or).

So `$username` is either the value of the parameter `'username'`, if it is defined, or an empty string.

Answer (score 5):

It's the [defined or operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Defined-Or). Like `||` but looks for whether the variable is defined, as opposed to being true:

```
my $number;
$number = '0';
my $var = $number // '1';

print "$var\n";
```

Will print `0`, as `$number` is defined.

However, substituting for `||`, which tests for trueness:

```
my $number;
$number = '0';
my $var = $number || '1';

print "$var\n";
```

Will print `1`, as, although `$number` is defined, it evaluates as false

Answer (score 4):

This is the [defined-or](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Defined-Or) operator. If `$cgi->param('username')` is `undef`, `$username` will be set to an empty string.